# SVN - Resolve as mine

Tags: svn, conflict, resolve

I was working today on a C# code using AnkhSVN on VisualStudio and when I tried to commit, SVN returned a conflict and I set as "resolve as mine".

Until this step, everything was OK, but then, SVN erased my conflicted class and put an old one.

It didn't generate any conflict file. Is there any chance for me to recover the file that SVN erased?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can revert that change.

Revert dialog is accessed via the Team > Revert context menu. 
http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lukasz, but the truth is: my modifications in the class wasn't commited, a simple revert doesn't work because it will return an old file.

Comment: I was developing in one class (the new one wasn't under version control). And SVN erased this one and put an old one... but I don't know any way to recover this